# Anylogic: Use individual RandomNumberGenerator for each ressource

Tags: java, random, anylogic

We are working on a simulation of a production chain of six machines connected in a series. For all of them, we need failure times etc. which are distributed differently.

I am looking for a way to implement an individual RNG for each of the resources used. We need six different RNGs. Unfortunately, we struggle to understand how to implement and use this. [Anylogic docu](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fstochastic%2FCustom_RNG.html) does not really help/explain. It says something about using the Java Random Class.

The example says: triangular( 5, 10, 25, myRNG )  - how to implement myRNG and is it an object or a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The myRNG that you state in your question has to be an instance of the class Random or of a subclass of Random.

Random is a Java class that you can freely use. To generate an instance of that class you would need to do
Random rand=new Random();
or you can use it directly in your distribution:

```
triangular( 5, 10, 25, new Random() )
```

Now a subclass is another class, different than the Random class, but inherits all of its properties. To create a subclass, you need to do it by yourself and learn Java in general and as a newbie I don't see why you would need it.

If you want 6 different RNG, i guess you would be ok with seeds in your random class so you can define and index that states each one of your seeds and do

```
triangular( 5, 10, 25, new Random(seeds.get(index)) )
```

assuming you have a collection called seeds that stores all the seeds you want to use.